# Bootstrap datepicker, error when adding new locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap

When trying to add new locale, using instructions from here https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker getting an error on rails 3.2:

> ActionView::Template::Error (locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pl is
>   'text/x-script.perl', not 'application/javascript'

Comment: You forgot the _.js_ at the end of your filename.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the wrong file extension. You want `.js`, not `.pl`.